# Is it possible to dynamically loop through a table's columns?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have a trigger function for a table test which has the following code snippet:

```
IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN
    IF OLD.locked > 0 AND
 (       OLD.org_id <> NEW.org_id OR
            OLD.document_code <> NEW.document_code OR
            -- other columns ...
 )
THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Message';
-- more code
```

So I am statically checking all the column's new value with its previous value to ensure integrity. Now every time my business logic changes and I have to add new columns into that table, I will have to modify this trigger each time. I thought it would be better if somehow I could dynamically check all the columns of that table, without explicitly typing their name.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the information_schema, there is a view "columns". Execute a query to get all current columnnames from the table that fired the trigger:

```
SELECT 
    column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
    table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA 
AND 
    table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;
```

Loop through the result and there you go!

More information can be found in the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 12):

From 9.0 beta2 documentation about `WHEN` clause in triggers, which might be able to be used in earlier versions within the trigger body:

`OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*`

or possibly ([from 8.2 release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-8-2.html))

`IF row(new.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(old.*)`

Comment: Yes. If all you're doing is testing whether any column values have changed and you don't need to know the specific column(s) that have changed, Stephen's 2nd snippet is definitely the way to go. Concise and never needs maintenance!

Comment: Archangel might find it useful to combine that test with knowledge of whether `Locked > 0` and whether `locked` has changed. Additionally `IS DISTINCT FROM` deals with nulls in a less surprising way than `<>`

Answer (score 4):

In Postgres 9.0 or later add a [**`WHEN` clause**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) to your trigger definition (`CREATE TRIGGER` statement):

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW)  -- parentheses required!
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ...;
```

Only possible for triggers `BEFORE` / `AFTER` **`UPDATE`**, where both `OLD` and `NEW` are defined. You'd get an exception trying to use this `WHEN` clause with `INSERT` or `DELETE` triggers.

And radically simplify the trigger *function* accordingly:

```
...
IF OLD.locked > 0 THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Message';
END IF;
...
```

No need to test `IF TG_OP='UPDATE' ...` since this trigger only works for `UPDATE` anyway.

Or move that condition in the WHEN clause, too:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.locked > 0
  AND OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ...;
```

Leaving only an unconditional `RAISE EXCEPTION` in your trigger function, which is only called when needed to begin with.

[Read the fine print:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-NOTES)

> In a `BEFORE` trigger, the `WHEN` condition is evaluated just before the
>   function is or would be executed, so using `WHEN` is not materially
>   different from testing the same condition at the beginning of the
>   trigger function. Note in particular that the `NEW` row seen by the
>   condition is the current value, as possibly modified by earlier
>   triggers. Also, a `BEFORE` trigger's `WHEN` condition is not allowed to
>   examine the system columns of the `NEW` row (such as `oid`), because those
>   won't have been set yet.
>
> In an `AFTER` trigger, the `WHEN` condition is evaluated just after the
>   row update occurs, and it determines whether an event is queued to
>   fire the trigger at the end of statement. So when an `AFTER` trigger's
>   `WHEN` condition does not return true, it is not necessary to queue an
>   event nor to re-fetch the row at end of statement. This can result in
>   significant speedups in statements that modify many rows, if the
>   trigger only needs to be fired for a few of the rows.

Related:

- [Fire trigger on update of columnA or ColumnB or ColumnC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435669/fire-trigger-on-update-of-columna-or-columnb-or-columnc/25436314?noredirect=1#comment86489239_25436314)

#### To also address the question title

> Is it possible to dynamically loop through a table's columns?

Yes. Examples:

- [Handle result when dynamic SQL is in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282882/handle-result-when-dynamic-sql-is-in-a-loop/46290770#46290770)
- [Removing all columns with given name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75573/removing-all-columns-with-given-name/75617#75617)

Answer (score 2):

[Iteration over RECORD variable inside trigger](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Iteration_over_RECORD_variable_inside_trigger)

Answer (score 1):

Use pl/perl or pl/python. They are much better suited for such tasks. **much** better.

You can also install [hstore-new](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/hstore-new/), and use it's row->hstore semantics, but that's definitely not a good idea when using normal datatypes.