# Updating a row with a trigger without causing an infinite loop

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.3, rule

I have a column called `updated` which is intended to show the last time that column was altered.

My first attempt at this was to create a trigger that changed the `updated` column to the value returned by `now()`. But because this trigger happens on an update event, it caused an infinite loop (updating the updated column causes the trigger to fire).

I also tried implementing a rule to do this with similar effects.

I can't imagine that this is something I am forced to do on the application layer when ever I call and update function. So how can I update that row's updated column without causing infinite loops?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26284695/2101267

Comment: Why would changing a column in a trigger cause an infinite loop? I don't see how `new.some_column := now()` could ever do that.

Comment: I believe because the trigger fires on update. So when update my_table SET updated = now(); executes it is updating the row, which then causes the update trigger to fire again, and update the row again, and loops in that cycle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I automatically update a timestamp in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556474/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-timestamp-in-postgresql)

Comment: Well,  you shouldn't be running an `UPDATE` on the table that is being "triggered" - and you don't need that in the first place. Just assign the new value to the row. See Flimzy's answer. That is really the only correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this in other applications by checking the field I am changing and if nothing is changed, then I do not do the update.  If you can check the updated column and if it is within the last N seconds, do not do the update.  This should stop the infinite loop.  Pick the number you want for N, so you can know the update timestamp is always within N seconds.

Comment: No offence, but this answer gives me the impression that you are doing something fundamentally wrong in your trigger.

Comment: No offence taken.  My answer is based on external code from an event trigger, not sql.  It was the only way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.updated = OLD.updated THEN
        NEW.updated = NOW()
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER table_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update()
```

This way you aren't in a loop--you only update the value once (before the UPDATE is executed), and you also don't clobber the value, if for some reason you want to set `updated` explicitly (as in when importing old data from backup, for instance).