# How to address moddatetime apparently bypassing precision of column?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, precision

We have a database where every timestamp is defined as `timestamp(3) with time zone`.  We noticed that in some cases we were getting back timestamps with 6 fractional digits, not 3.  I tracked this down to only happening in out `update_date` columns, and only if it was updated via `moddatetime`.

Does anybody have experience with gracefully fixing this?

I tested manual inserts, updates, from literal, from now(), etc and none of those cause the issue.

I'm aware of being able to fix this by casting to `::timestamptz(3)` wherever we use this field, but this will add a lot of mess, plus I am concerned about the performance if we need to do `... WHERE date_trunc('milliseconds', update_date) > other_tz3_value`.

The best I've come up with would be changing the index we have on update_date to a functional index on `date_trunc('milliseconds', update_date)`, but again, this seems clunky.

The tables in question have a trigger like:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE moddatetime(update_date);
```

My expectation would be that no matter how a value is inserted into a timestamp(3) field, it always comes back with no more than 3 fractional digits.

Comment: So what does this `moddatetime()` do?

Comment: moddatetime is a function provided by the extension with the same name.  

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/contrib-spi.html :


    F.37.5. moddatetime — Functions for Tracking Last Modification Time
moddatetime() is a trigger that stores the current time into a timestamp field. This can be useful for tracking the last modification time of a particular row within a table.


    To use, create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger using this function. Specify a single trigger argument: the name of the column to be modified. The column must be of type timestamp or timestamp with time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with the `moddatetime` function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556527/1171775) shows an example of using a custom trigger. We can modify it to define the precision of the generated timestamp like so:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_column()   
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified = current_timestamp(3);
    RETURN NEW;   
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```