# How to put a copy of a row into another table on update?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I used this answer to autoupdate timestamp of last change [How do I automatically update a timestamp in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556474/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-timestamp-in-postgresql).

Now, I wonder how I can copy the old version of the row to another table, like `versions` when this trigger runs? It would be inserted to `versions` table every time I modify the row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE versions (
   obsoleted timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
   oldrow jsonb NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION vers_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO versions VALUES (current_timestamp, to_json(OLD));
   RETURN OLD;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER vers_trig AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON atable
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE vers_trig();
```

This will write the old version of the row to `versions`, together with the transaction timestamp of the statement that did it.