# How to update columns automatically in Postgres when we insert a new row?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two columns in specific table in Postgres. When new row is inserted, I want to know how to automatically insert data in two column [image]

So if I have a table insert table_name( nombre) values ('xxxxxx'). I want that creation_date(current day) and creation_user(current user in database) also inserted in the table.

Thanks for your help.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, that solves

```
"creation_date" timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

see this question: [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556474/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-timestamp-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks Kopper how Can do the same to the creation_user?

Comment: I think we can use current_user from postgress... Thanks a lot.