# update column date to today if any value is modified

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I need to modify the column ***last_update_date*** to today's date only if any other value of the table ***Table1*** is modified.
The code throws an error if the value to be modified is the column ***last_update_date***.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION date_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $date$

BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            UPDATE erp.tb_customer SET last_update_date = current_date;
    ELSIF (OLD.last_update_date != NEW.last_update_date) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error not possible to modify the date';
    END IF;
```

Comment: and why didn't you post the code see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: We can't troubleshoot your code if you don't post it.

Comment: @nbk sorry I am new. I've just posted it

Comment: This is a trigger function. Did you create a trigger that uses it?

Comment: write a trrigger function SEE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556474/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-timestamp-in-postgresql

Comment: @nbk I am not used to write advanced sql code... why is my code not working?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know much about trigger. In my case, the date needts to be updated ONLY IF someone modifies any other value of the other variables...

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems.

you need a trigger

postgres thows an error when you send your code.

the Syntax can look like you see below

> ```
> CREATE tABLE erp(myid int , last_update_date timestamp)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION date_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $date$
>
> BEGIN
>     IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
>             NEW.last_update_date = current_date;
>     ELSIF (OLD.last_update_date != NEW.last_update_date) THEN
>         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error not possible to modify the date';
>     END IF;
> END;
> $date$ language 'plpgsql';
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER erp_audit
> BEFORE UPDATE ON  erp
>     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION date_change();
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5361c965ed8f41a62ce02b1bed2be9f1)*

As INSTEAD OF TRIGGER, it would look like, but that s for much more extensive functionality

> ```
> CREATE tABLE erp(myid int , last_update_date timestamp)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW erp_view AS SELECT * FROM erp;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION date_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $date$
>
> BEGIN
>     IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
>             NEW.last_update_date = current_date;
>     ELSIF (OLD.last_update_date != NEW.last_update_date) THEN
>         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error not possible to modify the date';
>     END IF;
> END;
> $date$ language 'plpgsql';
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit
> INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON erp_view
>     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION date_change();
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c517133321547f19d75200f5c49c31b5)*

Comment: Why do you need a view? Doesn’t make sense to me

Comment: run the fiddle without the view and you get an error that tables can't have a instead of trgger

Comment: Then don’t use instead of. Never needed it for something like this