# Postgresql notify on query result changes

Tags: postgresql, triggers, notify

I have a sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM recipes 
         WHERE lock != '') AS count
```

and I want a notification whenever the result changes. It would be ideal when I only get a notification when the value is 0 or >0. Does anyone has a solution approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a trigger on `recipes`:

```
create or replace function recipes_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    payload text;
begin
    payload:= exists(select 1 from recipes where lock <> '')::int;
    perform pg_notify('recipes', payload);
    return null;
end $$;

create trigger recipes_trigger
after insert or update or delete on recipes
for each statement execute procedure recipes_trigger();
```

A client listening on the channel `recipes` will get a notification with the payload `0` or `1` after each insert/update/delete on the table.

Comment: Very nice solution! I would not have come to that solution and would have kept me at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25435669/6229375 .