# create a procedure based on column data change in postgrersql

Tags: postgresql

[Fire trigger on update of columnA or ColumnB or ColumnC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435669/fire-trigger-on-update-of-columna-or-columnb-or-columnc/25436314#25436314)
Set up the scene

```
begin;
create temp table account_details(email text primary key, username text, password text);
insert into account_details(email, username, password) values('a.com','b','c'),('b.com','d','e');
commit;
```

create function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_insert_account_details()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'hello world';
END
$$;
```

create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_account_details
AFTER UPDATE ON account_details
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.email    IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.email
   OR OLD.username IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.username
   OR OLD.password IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.password)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_insert_account_details();
```

Trying to update:

```
update account_details set username = 'username1' where email = 'a.com';
```

The result: notify_insert_account_details() fired. but didn't execute the update clause.

```
NOTICE:  hello world
ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function notify_insert_account_details()
```

**My question: how sophisticated this procedure/function notify_insert_account_details() Can become, let's say linked within 3 table. Can anyone showcase an example/demo?**

Comment: What the error says: you are missing a `return new; ` in your trigger function

Comment: As far as `how sophisticated` the trigger can become? It is virtually unlimited, If you can write valid code and *return new* (or null) then you can put it in a trigger.