# IS DISTINCT FROM vs NOT EQUAL for non-null columns in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, null, distinct

I'm defining a trigger similar to the code posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436314).

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_account_details
AFTER UPDATE ON account_details
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.email    IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.email
   OR OLD.username IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.username
   OR OLD.password IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.password) 
EXECUTE FUNCTION notify_insert_account_details();
```

However, let's say that `email`, `username`, and `password` are not NULLABLE columns.

It's my understanding that you use `IS DISTINCT FROM` when a column is nullable, but in my case, all of these values are `NOT NULL`.

In this case, is it still correct to use `IS DISTINCT FROM`, or should it simply be something like this instead?

```
WHEN (OLD.email    != NEW.email
   OR OLD.username != NEW.username
   OR OLD.password != NEW.password)
```

I'd imagine this latter would not only be more correct, but also faster, because no null check is performed. Is this correct?

Comment: From the docs [Comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html):  *For non-null inputs, IS DISTINCT FROM is the same as the <> operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one input is null it returns true. Similarly, IS NOT DISTINCT FROM is identical to = for non-null inputs, but it returns true when both inputs are null, and false when only one input is null. Thus, these predicates effectively act as though null were a normal data value, rather than “unknown”.* So probably no difference. Test to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that using IS DISTINCT FROM is not necessary for non-nullable columns, and using the != operator instead would be more appropriate and likely faster since no null check is needed.

Therefore, you can use the following code for your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_account_details
AFTER UPDATE ON account_details
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.email != NEW.email
OR OLD.username != NEW.username
OR OLD.password != NEW.password)
EXECUTE FUNCTION notify_insert_account_details();
```

This will ensure that the trigger only fires when the email, username, or password values are actually updated.

Comment: `IS DISTINCT FROM` is a generalization of `<>`. In this particular case (all columns are non-nullable) they behave in the same way.